# Möbius Transformation help

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry

Hey guys I need help on these 2 questions that I am having trouble on.

1) Show that the Möbius transformation $z \rightarrow \frac{2}{1-z}$ sends the unit circle and the line $x = 1$ to the lines $x = 1$ and $x = 0$, respectively.

2) Now deduce from this that the non-Euclidean distance between the unit circle and the line $x = 1$ tends to zero as these non-Euclidean lines approach the x-axis.

I know that the non-euclidean distance between the lines $x=0$ and $x=1$ goes to zero as $y$ approachs $\infty$.

But I dont know how to deduce that the unit circle would go to $x=1$ and $x=1$ to $x=0$ and how would I deduce from this. Its from my old past tests and I am trying to practice but I got stuck on this question.

Please help out thank you

Comment: What is the "non-Euclidean distance" in the context of this question?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: We can embed the complex plane into $\Bbb R^3$ with the map $$z\mapsto\left(\frac{z+\overline z}{|z|^2+1},\frac{i(z-\overline z)}{|z|^2+1},\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1}\right).$$ The "non-Euclidean distance between two points in $\Bbb C$ is most likely a reference to the distance between the images of the points under this map. (We can also talk about the "distance from $\infty$" with this distance, which we can't do with the usual metrics.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** the map is completely determined by its image on 3 points. So, compute the image of 3 points on the circle: $z=-1$, $z=i$ and $z=1$.

Comment: Nice hint . +1.

Answer (score 2):

These are exercises 8.6.5, 8.6.6 from "The Four Pillars of Geometry." I'll use the terminology of the book.

---

#1:

Call the transform $\varphi(z) = \dfrac{2}{1-z}$.

We know that Möbius transformations send non-Euclidean lines (circles and lines) to non-Euclidean lines. If we calculate the image of three points from the unit circle, we can uniquely determine the image of the unit circle as a whole.

Pick three points from the unit circle, say $\{-1, 1, i\}$. We have:
$$
\varphi(-1) = 1,\quad \varphi(1) = \infty,\quad \varphi(i) = \frac{2}{1-i} = 1 + i
$$

All points lie on the line $x = 1$. Hence, the image of the unit circle is the line $x = 1$.

Similarly for the line $x = 1$, pick the points $\{1, \infty, i + 1\}$:
$$
\varphi(1) = \infty,\quad \varphi(\infty) = 0,\quad \varphi(1+i) = 2i
$$

All points lie on the line $x = 0$. Hence, the image of the line $x = 1$ is the line $x = 0$.

---

#2:

We will show that the non-Euclidean distance between the unit circle and line $x = 1$ approaches zero as both non-Euclidean lines approach the point $1$ on the real axis.

Consider a point $p_1$ on the unit circle approaching the point $1$, and another point $p_2$ on the line $x = 1$ approaching the point $1$. Their images under $\varphi$ both approach $\infty$ on the lines $x = 1$ and $x = 0$ respectively by #1. Since we know that the non-Euclidean distance is invariant under all Möbius transformations, and we also know that the distance between the lines $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ approaches $0$ as $y$ approaches $\infty$, it follows that the non-Euclidean distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$ approaches $0$ as they approach the $x$ axis.